# Is it possible to print out the state space using SPIN?

Tags: visualization, state-space, spin, promela

I would like SPIN to print out the computed state space, so that I can make its visualization and then manually explore it. Is that possible?

I have already checked such flags as -DCHECK and -DVERBOSE, but I guess, that those are not what I am looking for...

Comment: Without having ever used it, it looks like this variant of Spin has built-in support for the kinds of visualisation that might interest you: https://code.google.com/p/erigone/

Comment: I want to make visualization myself for some reasons, that's why built-in tools is not a good option for me..

Comment: You are looking for the entire state space or just the state vector at a particular execution point?  Are you interested in states in the state vector that are internal to SPIN, such as the control state (like a program counter) for each proctype or just the global and local state that you define?

Comment: @GoZoner I am looking for the entire state space containing only variables from the state vector, i.e. without internal ones. As for now, I am using a method similar to one implemented in SpinSpider.

Answer (score 0):

No, currently there is no graphical output of the searched state space in `spin`. It is possible to plot the program graph using graphviz `dot`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24637962/1959808).