# How to print all states in Promela/SPIN

Tags: multicore, spin, promela, model-checking

I would like to print all states when checking my model. We do get a trail file when an assertion violation occurs but I want to see the states even when there are no assertion violations. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the motivation for this?  To confirm that the model is 'hitting' certain points?

Answer (score 6):

One option is to compile `pan` with the `gcc` flag `-DVERBOSE` and watch the full details of the verification run. Of course the run will take a while and will spit excessive output, but you will see all the states as they are visited (the format is not very easy to read, but may be sufficient for your purposes).

Another option to see the state graphs of individual processes is

```sh
./pan -D | dot -Tps | ps2pdf - pan.pdf
```

This will create a multi-page PDF where each page is a process (including the `never` claim).

Comment: Second part of answer (per-process graph) is probably not what the OP wanted.